# Multiple String Comparison At once

Tags: excel, vba

I have a silly piece of code that tests if a variable is a certain string:

```
If Target.Cell.Value = "1M" or Target.Cell.Value = "1N" or Target.Cell.Value = "1O" Then
...
End If
```

Is there a way to compress that If statement - ie compare against a list or something like that?

Comment: After testing for the different values do you apply a different action depending on the values or just need to know if the target contains any of the values tested?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select Case Target.Cell.Value
Case "1M","1N","10" 
     ...
end select
```

Comment: Like this, the cleanest

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function valueInArray(myValue As Variant, myArray As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If CStr(myValue) = CStr(myArray(cnt)) Then
            valueInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cnt

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print valueInArray("test", Array("ta", "to", 1, 2, "test"))
    Debug.Print valueInArray("test1", Array("ta", "to", 1, 2, "test"))

End Sub
```

The `valueInArray` returns a boolean result, telling you whether the `myValue` is present in the array.

Comment: Why don't you just do the test *while* you're looping through the array, then you can skip processing the whole array if your value is found?

Comment: @Rory - looping through array is really fast + the early exit from the loop still counts as the same complexity - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967738/what-is-big-o-of-a-loop

Comment: But adding the function call to Match does add unnecessary overhead if you're going to loop through the whole array anyway. I guess I just don't see the point of doing both.

Comment: @Rory - now I remember why I did it :) - in general, the only think the loop does is to convert the `MyArray` to a string array. Then, it simply tries the `Match()` and thus it returns the answer.

Comment: @Rory - if you remove the loop completely, and you leave only `valueInArray = Not IsError()` the following would be false: `valueInArray(3, Array(3, 4, 5, 6))`

Comment: I can see that - I just don't see why you wouldn't simply test the values as you go and stop if it's found. What's the benefit of looping through the whole array and then calling `Match` which has to loop through the whole array again? I didn't say remove the *loop* - I said do the check inside the loop and remove the `MATCH`.

Comment: @Rory - it was probably because the loop was added after the `Match()` part :) But, yes, w/o the `Match()` it is probably better.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
If Instr(1, ",1M,1N,1O,", "," & Target.Value & ",") <> 0 Then
...
End If
```

If you don't want the comparison to be case sensitive, add `, vbTestCompare` to the end the `Instr` check.

Comment: @Vityata Yup - I forgot to add a key bit when copying from the original code!

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation of @Vityata's excellent answer, which uses a [ParamArray](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml) rather than a variant array argument:

```
Function Matches(s As String, ParamArray targets()) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(targets)
        If s = targets(i) Then
            Matches = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    Matches = False
End Function
```

Used like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = "1N"
    If Matches(s, "1M", "1N", "10") Then
        Debug.Print s & " is valid"
    Else
        Debug.Print s & " is invalid"
    End If
    s = "2M"
    If Matches(s, "1M", "1N", "10") Then
        Debug.Print s & " is valid"
    Else
        Debug.Print s & " is invalid"
    End If   
End Sub
```

Output:

```
1N is valid
2M is invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

To test if a cell value equals a list of values try this:

1. Create a constant with the list of values to be tested:
   In this case let's create two list

   ```
   Const kComp1 As String = "1M,1N,10"  
   Const kComp2 As String = "1,0,M,N"
   ```
2. Then apply this function to the cells we need to test

   ```
   Function Cell_CompareValue(sCell As String, sComp As String) As Boolean
   Dim aComp As Variant
       aComp = Chr(167) & Replace(sComp, Chr(44), Chr(167)) & Chr(167)
       Cell_CompareValue = InStr(aComp, Chr(167) & sCell & Chr(167))
       End Function
   ```
3. Example
   Let's apply the function for both constants to the values in the range `B2:B8` showing the results for both lists in columns `C` and `D`

   ```
   Sub TEST_Values()
   Dim rgTrg As Range, rgCll As Range

       Set rgTrg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sht(4)").Range("B3:B9")

       For Each rgCll In rgTrg.Cells
           With rgCll
               .Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell_CompareValue(.Value2, kComp1)
               .Offset(0, 2).Value = Cell_CompareValue(.Value2, kComp2)
       End With: Next

       End Sub
   ```

**Results:**
[image]